# Film noir character archetypes

Tags: savage-worlds

I have been looking online for a list of film noir character archetypes for a Savage Worlds campaign I am running. I have came up with a few: Private Investigator, Grifter, Police officer, Mobster...

Is there a good site or resource where I can find a list of published Noir archetypes for Savage Worlds?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a film genre and contains no RPG-specific problem for us to solve.

Comment: The Deadlands Noir core book lists quite a few.

Comment: Re: on-topic discussion - "A list of published SW noir archetypes" is purely on topic.

Comment: @mxyzplk No it isn't. Savage Worlds setting books don't deal in "archetypes" and such a list would be weird and out of place (zero utility; waste of paper) in a SW setting book due to how SW handles this aspect of characters. If this wants to be on-topic, it's going to have to abandon asking about Noir archetypes entirely and ask about lists of published Noir Professional Edges and Background Edges. Having seen this question evolve through edits, that would very likely not solve the asker's actual problem anyway.

Comment: @mxyzplk Also witness the accepted answer: it's for a book that happens lists purely genre archetypes, with no SW-specific connection. A list that could be gotten by doing [real-world non-RPG campaign research](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/570/are-campaign-research-questions-on-topic).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about archetypes in the Noir genre (film, books, games) vs. something directly related to published SW media.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thrilling Tales has some archetypes as does Realms of Cthulhu. Also, feel free to post your questions on the [PEG forums](http://www.peginc.com/forum/) or the [Google+ Savage Worlds Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114543562362623476863) as well. The Savage Worlds user base is far larger there, and they love talking about this stuff. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party to answer this question, but

[Streets of Bedlam: A Savage World of Crime & Corruption](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/103092/Streets-of-Bedlam-A-Savage-World-of-Crime-+-Corruption)

This is pretty much Savage Worlds Noir, or at least Savage Worlds Sin City, which is pretty close to the OP requirements. Only downside to my answer is you'll have to buy a copy; the link is to DriveThruRPG, but don't let that stop you looking for alternative suppliers.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get your hands on it, there's [Mutant & Masterminds Noir](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932442375) even if you're using Savage Worlds rules MM books usually have the first chapter as very informative outline of a particular genre over the course of the years.

For example if I would be tasked to explain to someone with no idea of fantasy what the genre is, I would simply read them the first chapter from MM's [Warriors and Warlocks](http://greenroninstore.com/products/warriors-and-warlocks-pdf) even if the book bills itself as **merely** about the sword and sorcery subgenre.

So I imagine the noir handbook has an equally informative first chapter and example characters.

Comment: My downvote is for "bad speculation." That last paragraph implies that you don't have first-hand knowledge of what's in the book, and you're guessing based on other works.